# Will my gdb work when using templates?

Tags: c++, debugging, templates, gdb

I plan to templatize a container class which can be used for various data types. I currently have a big concern:

- Will my gdb still work in the template? Can I set breakpoints, print values, print stack traces, etc in a class template as in a normal member function?
- Where are the limits? Are there serious restrictions or weird behavior to expect?

I'm not talking about debugging the template instantiation itself and I'm also not talking about extensive metaprogramming.

I did some research on the internet, but search results are full with real template debugging and it's hard to find an answer on this (hopefully) relatively simple question.

Comment: Why not just try it? Should work fine though.

Comment: See also [c++ - GDB breakpoints do not hit template functions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600798/gdb-breakpoints-do-not-hit-template-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal Class

```
class foo
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    foo(int n = 0):x(n) {cout<<"foo::foo(int)"<<endl;}
    ~foo() {cout<<"foo::~foo()"<<endl;}
};

To put the breakpoint, we follow as below
$gdb: b foo::foo(int)
      b foo::~foo()
```

=========================================================

Template class Example

```
template<typename T>
class bar
{
private:
    T x;
public:
    bar(T n = 0):x(n) {cout<<"bar::bar(int)"<<endl;}
    ~bar() {cout<<"bar::~bar()"<<endl;}
};

To put the breakpoint, we follow as below
$gdb: b bar<int>::bar(int)
      b foo<int>::~bar()
```

The only thing we need to understand is(which I guess confuted you), that when we debug **template class**, we can not use the break point like `bar<T>::bar()`. When program runs, program would instantiate the **template class** with a particular type as `bar<int>::bar()`.

Apart from that, there is no difference while debugging the non-template vs template based class. Only thing we need to consider is, template bases class would be bit verbose and it takes some time to understand especially.

Answer (score 3):

You can break with gdb on all instances of a template with using the gdb `rbreak` command! That makes the usage much! easier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template < typename T>
T Foo(T t) { return t; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo<int>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Foo<std::string>("Hallo") << std::endl;
}
```

You can use gdb as follows:

```
gdb> rbreak Foo<.*>
Breakpoint 4 at 0x400cc5: file main.cpp, line 5.
int Foo<int>(int);
Breakpoint 5 at 0x400cda: file main.cpp, line 5.
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > Foo<std::string>(std::string);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do identical to this solution but get a `Function "_Z3FooIiET_S0_" not defined in "/tmp/a.cpp".
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) 
` for some reason.